# Approximate spectrum of a linear operator on sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be the bounded linear operator on $l^1$ defined by 
$$T(x) = \Big ( \sum _{k \ge 2} x_k \Big) e_1 + \sum_{j=2}^\infty x_{j-1} e_j, $$

Show $\sigma_{ap}(T) \subseteq \bar{B}(0,1) \cup \{ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \}$.

What I have: By solving $\lambda I - T = 0$, I could show $\sigma_{p}(T)= \{ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \}$. Also, $||T|| \le 2$.  But none of these give me what I need. Any hints?

Update 1:

I think it is possible to work with the dual operator. Noting that $\sigma(T)= \sigma_{ap}(T)\cup \sigma_p(T')$. It is easy to compute $\sigma_p(T')$ (comments below) in this case. Might this help?

Update 2: I have forgot to include the eigenvalue for $\sigma_{ap}(T)$.

Comment: Since $\|Tx\|_1\geq \|x\|_1$, what I get here is that $\sigma_{ap}(T)\cap B(0,1)=\emptyset$, where $B(0,1)$ is the open ball. Not really what you are asking...

Comment: I couldn't find a way to simplify the case when $|\lambda|>1$, $\lambda \not= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ under than inequality bash. On the other hand, if we look at the dual operator, $T'$ on $l^\infty$, $\sigma_p(T') = \bar{B}(0,1) \cup \{ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \} \setminus \{1 \}$. But again, it is hard to compute the approximate and residual of dual.